# My gallery buttons in js won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a gallery to use this in my own page, I've placed controller divs correctly, I've made a script but it won't work. That's it:

```
function changePhoto(id) {

         var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo_img");
         var x = document.getElementById("br_hidden");
            y.style.border = "2px solid grey";
            x.style.display = "block";

         var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
         y.src = z;

         var ui = document.getElementById("overlay");
         ui.style.display = "block";


         var next = document.getElementById("next");
         var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
         var identity = id;

            next.onclick = function(identity) {
                var id = identity/1 + 1;
                var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
                y.src = z;
            }
            prev.onclick = function(identity) {
                var id = identity;
                if(id == 1) {
                    var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
                } else {
                    id = id/1 + 1;
                    var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
                }
                y.src = z;
            }
     }
```

I mean last two functions, I attached onclick event but it returns NaN in console. This is html code:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="prev"><--</div>
    <div id="next">--></div>
    <img src="" id="baza_big_photo_img">
</div>

    <div class="br4 hidden" id="br_hidden"></div>

    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(1);"><img src="./zdjecia/1.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(2);"><img src="./zdjecia/2.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(3);"><img src="./zdjecia/3.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(4);"><img src="./zdjecia/4.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(5);"><img src="./zdjecia/5.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(6);"><img src="./zdjecia/6.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(7);"><img src="./zdjecia/7.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
    <div class="baza_zdjecia" onclick="changePhoto(8);"><img src="./zdjecia/8.jpg" class="fitimg"></div>
```

I think there is a bug with sending id twice through second functions but I don't know how to fix it, help me please:)

Comment: What "returns NaN" in the console?  Be specific.  This is probably also a great opportunity to start using a debugger.  In your browser's debugging tools you can place a breakpoint inside your code and the execution will pause on that breakpoint, you can then step through the code line by line as it executes and examine the actual values of your variables.  Which one isn't a number?  Which one isn't what you expect?

Comment: next.onclick and prev.onclick there I'm sending identity variable through function, but it has undefined value, why, after I set this value here: var identity = id;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you are illegally transforming you id variable....

```
next.onclick = function(identity) {
  var id = identity/1 + 1;
  var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
  y.src = z;
}
```

...this is why you are returning NAN in your console

try..

```
var id = identity += 1;
```

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: How is the original code "illegally transforming the id variable"?  And how does the proposed change resolve that?

Comment: Any reason why people are voting this down?

Comment: Because performing a division of a string (representing a number) by itself will immediately throw an NAN result.  Performing the standard incremental pattern i.e i+= 1, will automatically try and convert whatever string to a number before adding the increment to it. Thanks

Comment: @TrumpBotIV: You sure about that?  https://jsfiddle.net/76josngn/  Seems that the division is working just fine, but the `+=` is appending the value as a string.  Causing an entirely different result.

Comment: Fair enough, I agree you're right. I know I've bumped into similar situations where the other incremental operator has been required and thought we had a match...

Comment: @TrumpBotIV: Without knowing more about the specifics of how JavaScript interprets values under the hood, my guess is that the `/` operator on a numeric string defaults to attempting to interpret the string as a number (since `/` wouldn't mean anything on a string), but since the `+` operator has a perfectly valid meaning to a string and since converting a number to a string is safer than the other way around then any use of the `+` operator would be as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments it sounds like the `identity` variable in the `onclick` events isn't what you expect.  Take a look at how that variable is being set:

```
var identity = id;

next.onclick = function(identity) {
    var id = identity/1 + 1;
    var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
    y.src = z;
}
```

You *do* set a value to that variable, but in the `onclick` function you declare a *new* local variable called `identity`, which has nothing to do with the one you set outside that function.  Whatever the browser may be sending as the first (if any) parameter to that event isn't going to be your `identity` variable, and probably isn't going to be numeric at all.

You don't need the function parameter, just remove it entirely:

```
var identity = id;

next.onclick = function() {
    var id = identity/1 + 1;
    var z = "./zdjecia/" + id + ".jpg";
    y.src = z;
}
```